# quotechar is not functioning in pandas read_fwf

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

I have comma(s) `,` inside pandas dataframe column values like below. I have tried all parameters provided by pandas `read_fwf` and `read_csv` methods but nothing seems to be working.

**Note:** I'm ready txt.gz file and I cannot use StringIO

*Sample Input:*

```
"NTE","","","NANTONG JIACHENG GARMENTS CO., LTD","P",0,1
"LEH","","","WUHAN YIZHAO TRADING CO. , LTD.","P",0,2
"ARN","","","Clinical Diagnostic Solutions, Inc.","P",0,7
```

*My code*

```
pd.read_fwf(input_filepath,compression='gzip',sep=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True,header=None,nrows=1000, usecols=[0,1,7])
```

*Expected Output*

```
      0   1   2                                    3    4   5   6
0   NTE| NaN| NaN| NANTONG JIACHENG GARMENTS CO. LTD |  P|  0|  1
1   LEH| NaN| NaN| WUHAN YIZHAO TRADING CO. LTD.     |  P|  0|  2
2   ARN| NaN| NaN| Clinical Diagnostic Solutions Inc.|  P|  0|  7
```

**sample data file added**
[data_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H-lMsOjbghJ79Qvu1THExXtsx0UjleGB/view?usp=sharing)

I only consider `usecols=[0,1,7]` for the processing.

I'm looking for pandas way of resolving it instead of using regex as there is a lot of such commas in my data. Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive chat:

```py
import io
import re
import pandas as pd
import tarfile

#Working on the gunzipped and untarred txt file
f = 'RequestoEAP_20220220_test.txt'
s1 = list()
s2 = list()

re_brackets = re.compile('\((.*)\)')

with open(f, 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        s1.append(l[:23])
        if (m := re_brackets.search(l)):
            s2.append(m[1])
        else:
            s2.append('')

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(s1)), sep=' ', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(s2)), sep=',', header=None)

df = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           0             1           0    1   2   3    4   5   6   ... 24  25  26         27  28   29                                                 30    31    32
0  2022-02-20  00:00:10.061  6016293021  JKT  ID  AP  SUB  ID  AP  ...  N   0   1  FOCIDIGTW NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
1  2022-02-20  00:00:10.061  8910112455  BJX  MX  AM  VSA  MX  AM  ...  5   0   1  980446133 NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
2  2022-02-20  00:00:10.061  9640651705  NLU  MX  AM  MTY  MX  AM  ...  G   0   1  988122138 NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
3  2022-02-20  00:00:10.061  9410678701  JKT  ID  AP  SRG  ID  AP  ...  N   0   1  FOCIDIGTW NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
4  2022-02-20  00:00:10.061  7120027014  BOM  IN  AP  CPH  DK  EU  ...  D   0   1  530852429 NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
5  2022-02-20  00:00:10.062  9473172225  LCY  GB  EU  ZLS  GB  EU  ...  N   0   1  135104716 NaN  NaN  jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender).................  main  True
6  2021-11-09  00:00:00.200  5988409265  PVG  CN  CN  NTE  FR  EU  ...  P   0   1  969762616 NaN  NTE                    jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender   NaN   NaN
7  2021-11-09  00:00:00.202  9876963305  SZX  CN  CN  LEH  FR  EU  ...  P   0   2  606734345 NaN  NaN                    jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender   NaN   NaN
8  2021-11-09  00:00:00.292  5697446005  TMB  US  AM  ARN  SE  EU  ...  P   0   7  962003035 NaN  STO                    jms:WebSphere_MQ-default-sender   NaN   NaN
```

---

Before the extensive chat:

```py
import io
s = """"NTE","","","NANTONG JIACHENG GARMENTS CO., LTD","P",0,1
"LEH","","","WUHAN YIZHAO TRADING CO. , LTD.","P",0,2
"ARN","","","Clinical Diagnostic Solutions, Inc.","P",0,7
"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep=',', header=None)
```

You had the wrong separator and you specified compression, which all don't seem to be necessary.
Output:

```
     0   1   2                                    3  4  5  6
0  NTE NaN NaN   NANTONG JIACHENG GARMENTS CO., LTD  P  0  1
1  LEH NaN NaN      WUHAN YIZHAO TRADING CO. , LTD.  P  0  2
2  ARN NaN NaN  Clinical Diagnostic Solutions, Inc.  P  0  7
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm reading .txt.gz file so I can't use `StringIO` :(

Comment: Using the StringIO is only to test your example. If your file is indeed like you say, adjust accordingly: `pd.read_csv(filename, compression='gzip', sep=',', header=None)`

Comment: still the same, its not considering the comma(,) in the column value

Comment: In that case, you should attach a part of your file in the question, because with the snippet you showed in the question, it worked.

Comment: I added sample data file to the question, please have a look

Comment: I've seen the file. I'll update my answer once I'm done. What you have sent is not what you originally posted in your file. It's a log file that needs some preprocessing before you can enter it into `read_csv`.

Comment: Please check `read_fwf` I read only considering columns 0,1, 7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242570/discussion-between-prinsedje80-and-vicky).