# Creating t-1 column with lag values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe

```
{'Year': {0: 2017, 1: 2018, 2: 2019, 3: 2017, 4: 2018, 5: 2019, 6: 2017, 7: 2018, 8: 2019}, 'Total_articles_per_year': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 1}, 'Total_articles_2017': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2}, 'Total_articles_2018': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 7, 4: 7, 5: 7, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3}, 'Total_articles_2019 ': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}}
```

I want to create a new column `t-1`.

Condition for this column will be:

- If df[`Year'] == 2017`, `df[t-1] = NaN`
- If df[`Year'] == 2018`, for value if `df[t-1]` take value from `Total_articles_per_year2017`
- If df[`Year'] == 2019`, for value `if df[t-1]` take value from `Total_articles_per_year2018`

Expected output:

```
{'Year': {0: 2017, 1: 2018, 2: 2019, 3: 2017, 4: 2018, 5: 2019, 6: 2017, 7: 2018, 8: 2019}, 'Total_articles_per_year': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 1}, 'Total_articles_2017': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2}, 'Total_articles_2018': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 7, 4: 7, 5: 7, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3}, 'Total_articles_2019 ': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 't-1': {0: nan, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan, 4: 4.0, 5: 7.0, 6: nan, 7: 2.0, 8: 3.0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape values by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), so possible compare `Year` subtracted by `1` for previus year with add `Total_articles_`:

```
melt = df.melt(['Year'], ignore_index=False)
mask = 'Total_articles_' + melt['Year'].sub(1).astype(str) == melt['variable']
df['t-1'] = melt.loc[mask, 'value']
print (df)
   Year  Total_articles_per_year  Total_articles_2017  Total_articles_2018  \
0  2017                        2                    2                    1   
1  2018                        1                    2                    1   
2  2019                        0                    2                    1   
3  2017                        4                    4                    7   
4  2018                        7                    4                    7   
5  2019                        3                    4                    7   
6  2017                        2                    2                    3   
7  2018                        3                    2                    3   
8  2019                        1                    2                    3   

   Total_articles_2019   t-1  
0                     0  NaN  
1                     0  2.0  
2                     0  1.0  
3                     3  NaN  
4                     3  4.0  
5                     3  7.0  
6                     1  NaN  
7                     1  2.0  
8                     1  3.0
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: @jezrael, Could you please help me on this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334307/quotechar-is-not-functioning-in-pandas-read-fwf